# using TypeScript for 1 single file in a big project

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I've forked a very big project from GitHub and I've wrote a ~3000 lines plugin (single file) for it.
I would like to **start using TypeScript for just this 1 single file**.

As a starting point I only want to have the plain **old JS content inside the .ts file (since any JS is valid TS)** and then starting making minor incremental changes towards TS.
What I did was to install TypeScript in the project directory and made it so that TSC will compile my TypeScript file containing the old JS code into a .js file having the name the plugin had before.

The problem is this: How can I convert the plugin dependencies to TS?

Example:

the pre TS file, myPlugin.js, is the ~3000 lines file:

```
bigForkedApp.MyPlugin = function(bigForkedAppContext) {
    // alot of code goes here
}
```

When copying this code in **myPlugin.ts** and expecting it to translate nicely into **myPlugin.js**, the compiler complains it doesn't know who bigForkedApp is.

I'm expecting that after the transpilation, the ***bigForkedApp.MyPlugin*** function in myPlugin.js can be **called by the application just like before**.

Should I write somehow **.d.ts** definitions for **bigForkedApp** and **bigForkedAppContext**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since it's a JS (not TS) - you need to tell TypeScript who is "bigForkedApp", like this:

```
`declare var bigForkedApp: any;`
```